# use a 2-axes colormap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

Is there a practical way to use/define a "nice" Matplotlib color maps that would be dependent on two real variables `cmap2d(a1,a2)`, of course such as:  `0.<= a1 <= 1. & 0.<= a2 <= 1.` ?

Basically it should be defined as a regular colormap but defined on a 2d frame ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define a 2D colour map.

Because the output of your 2D colour map is univariate (let's forget about the RGB channels for now), you can always express it in two steps:

1. compute a function `f(a1, a2)`
2. pass the output of the function to the colour map of your choice.

Given the decomposition above, you don't need to worry too much about whether the colour map takes one or two (or more) arguments because you can always express it in terms of a normal 1D colour map.

If you are willing to treat the different channels as different variables, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# Create a grid of values
x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y = np.linspace(0, 1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# Apply some function
xx = xx ** 2
yy = np.sin(np.pi * yy)
# Plot as RGB values
img = np.transpose((xx, yy, np.zeros_like(xx)))
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Thanks. But then there wont be a unique significance, i.e.: (1) it will be not possible to guess the value from the color, (2) is not sure that there will be an univoque pair `(a1,a2)` giving a single color (one should pick a good function...)

Comment: Your points are valid but are a fundamental limitation of mapping to input arguments to a single output argument. I have updated the answer assuming that you are willing to represent each variable by one of the RGB channels.